# Getting wrong footer for custom transactionl email

Tags: magento-1, transactional-mail

This is my trans. email content:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
///custom text
{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

and Yes I checked the settings->conf->Design->trans emails -> header/footer template, but I am still getting the default one.

I am sending this trans email via a cronjob. This is my code:

```
$this->template = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load(201);
$mailClass = EmailFactory::getMailClass();
$mail = new $mailClass(
                $reminder->getData('name'),
                $reminder->getData('email'),
                $this->template->getTemplateSubject(),
                'html',
                $storeName,
                $storeEmail,
                $this->template,
                EmailFactory::getEmailModel(), // Mage::getModel('core/email')
                [
                   //some custom params here
                ]);
            try {
                $mail->send();
            }catch(Exception $error){
//log here
            }
```

The email is sent , i get the right content, but the footer and header is the default one. What am I missing ? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since running cronjobs, the store is set to the admin one and when it comes to sending transactional emails , it doesn't knows about stores, so I include my code between a store emulation:

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($reminder->getData('store_id'));
///my code here
$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($appEmulation);
```

**Extra Note:**

Please check if the `Disable Email Communications` is set to NO for the store you want to emulate. It can be found in: `System->Configurations->Advanced:System-> Mail Sending Settings`

Comment: A little note for everyone. Make sure that you have correctly set "package" and "theme" in System/Configuration >> General/Design/Package resp. /Themes. If you leave them empty (change design is only made by changes in System/Design) then you will fallback to default design after calling ->stopEnvironmentEmulation.